# Displaying null page on running my JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql. Upon giving the right input, data is not getting displayed. Code inside my jsp is not working too, but catch block executes correctly. Can you suggest me how to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<%
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/check2allowMultiQueries=true";
%>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="cprofile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="view" method="POST">
      <%
        String z = request.getParameter("code");          
        String query="Select * from check2 where CODE='"+z+"';";
        try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/check 2", "root", "");
          Statement st=con.createStatement();
          rs = st.executeQuery(query);

          while (rs.next()) {
      %>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td><%=rs.getString("NAME")%></td>>
          <td><%=rs.getString("MEDIUM")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString("CODE")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString("ADD1")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString("ADD2")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString("CK")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString("FK")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString("BOARD")%></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <%}
          } catch(Exception e) {
              out.println(e);
          }
      %>
```

Comment: If the catch block executes, what does it print? I guess there's an error somewhere can you supply that as part of your question?

Comment: You are catching the exception and printing it. This is the following piece of code i am referring to catch(Exception e)
 {
  out.println(e);
 }. Is it printing something ?

Comment: Sorry Guys. I just noticed that my question has been edited. I could not frame the question properly yesterday as I was leaving for my classes. Buddy's edit  changed the problem statement little bit.
 The issue I am facing is that, I am not able to print the table. I am just getting a blank page as output. Not even Exception statement is getting executed. Am sure that it would be a silly mistake/ Am a newbie- you could have known it from my coding style.  So am not able to fix it. Kindly help me to fix the bug.

Comment: @Knight In this piece of code con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/check 2", "root", ""); . Is the database name check 2 (do you have a space). And also you are not providing the password to connect to the database. Can you please check that

Comment: Yes, the database name has a space in between and there's no password so I have left it empty.I am using the same driver manager code in  other places and its working in those places.

Comment: Improved grammar and format source code